# MSSQL quote insensitive search

Tags: sql-server, accent-insensitive

How to make a quote insensitive search in SQL Server?

For example those city names should be considered equal:

```
Muggio'
Muggio
```

I know how to make a simple accent-insensitive search but I found nothing about quote-insensitive searches.

There is a collation or a tidy function I can use? Or I should preprocess the city name in my code?

Comment: Doesn't it find with like?

Comment: No, because the input string is `Muggio'` and the table stores `Muggio`: `SELECT * FROM Cities WHERE name LIKE 'Muggio'''` won't work (NB: the triple quote is not a typo, the first two are the single quote `'` correctly escaped)

Comment: Well, a full-text search should work. It has its own problems, though :)

Comment: How Luuan? Please paste some code

Comment: Have you tried a full text search?

Comment: Yes I tried but I didn't know how to make o' and ò equals, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(v VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('abc'''),
('abc')

DECLARE @f VARCHAR(20) = 'abc'''
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE v LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@f, '''', '') + '%'
```

Output:

```
abc'
abc
```

Comment: Ok, so there is no "magic" collation.. I should preprocess data removing quotes

Comment: No, actually you need to remove that charachter yourself before searching.

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.